# Reduce mobile data usage in webview

Tags: android, webview

can we reduce the mobile data usage, as in firefox , chrome consumes 1mb to browse web page at the same time a sample app of webview takes 3mb to load the same page(webpage: http://khulapicking.ampa.co.za), is there any websettings or any work around is there, please give some suggestion on it weather it is possible or not, i look forwarding to hear from you guys.

Thanks,
Arunkumar

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the content of the page using Chrome's developer tools (in chrome just hit F12). There go to the network tab and reload the page. You can see all the data transfers, types, protocols, compression, etc.

My best guess would be that Chrome support better compression than other browser, so if the server support that too, it might send the more compressed data.

Comment: Thanks, bro that's a nice suggestion but my problem is when i am using my sample browser app(webview) consuming same data as like chrome and firefox in wifi, But when i switch to mobile data it consumes 3 times more than that in wifi takes. So can you please tell me is there any API or methods in WebView to reduce the mobile data usage as like in chrome and firefox, Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case I would run the app in the simulator and launch another program that monitors the network, like Fiddler or Wireshark, to see the difference between the regular browser and the webview. I can only guess what's taking the extra data, but it's not really an educated guess (I would say statistics data being collected, local android sensor data being sent to the webview, etc., but these are all wild guesses)